# On-Demand Resources: Download request could not be completed

Tags: swift

I am developing my tvOS app and am hosting some content on an AWS bucket, however when I try and download the data using NSBundleResourceRequest

I get:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1008 "Download request could not be completed. 
Resources not found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Download request could not be completed.
Resources not found., NSUnderlyingError=0x12910bc00 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=404 "(null)"}}
```

I can clearly see the resources on the server and can download them manually. Just ODR is not working...any ideas?

Is there anyway to see what URL ODR thinks it should be looking at?

I've set the url in Asset Pack Manifest URL Prefix

Answer (score 0):

It was because I simply took the folder version of the assetpack and uploaded that...I needed to upload the binary version

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm running into the same issue and uploaded *.assetpack files, however I'm not sure if those are the "folder version" or "binary version" (and where would I find the other asset pack files than the ones I'm currently using?).